# open in same tab

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce

I am using an inline visual force page in standard layout where I have few links. Now clicking on it opens in a new tab, but my client wants to open it in the same tab itself.

I tried using `window.open(url);`

But this open in the same tab

I tried `window.open(url,'_self');`

This open the page inside the inline visual force page itself. but I want to open it in same tab? How to achieve this?`